# Find a formula for all pentagonal numbers which are also square numbers.

Tags: square-numbers

I can get the formula for n-th pentagonal number is $P_n=\frac{3n^2-n}{2}$, but I do not know how to get the formula which is also square number. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QecZ0.png)

Comment: You may find [OEIS sequence A046173](https://oeis.org/A046173) "Indices of square numbers that are also pentagonal." useful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $3n^2 - n = 2 m^2$ can be written as
$(6n-1)^2 - 1 = 24 m^2$.  The Diophantine equation
$x^2 - 1 = 24 m^2$ is a Pell equation.